# Browsers that do not cache to disk

Tags: browser, memorycache

Are there any known web browser implementations (or browser options) that explicitly do not cache pages (and other data) to disk?

I'm looking for an implementation that only caches to memory (obviously the cache is discarded when the process exits). I'm ignoring external disk write factors such as OS paging.

Comment: "I'm looking for an implementation that only caches to memory" is this a programming specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's possible to disable the cache in every major browser, wich solves your first problem.

if you want to cache to memory, you have to turn caching on again, configure a [ramdisk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrecoX2nsOM) and then set the caching-path to that ram-disk. in firefox, for example, you have to change [`Browser.cache.disk.parent_directory`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.cache.disk.parent_directory) in `about:config` to achive this - and i'm pretty sure other major browsers will have similar options.